# The "email" option for Alerting Destination is missing (Opendistro Elasticsearch/Kibana)

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

Hello and best wishes for everyone,

I am configuring alerting in Kibana Opendistro, but cannot find the opetion for "email" in the menu of the Alerting > Destination > Create.
I can see options for Amazon, Slack and Custom webhook. It is suppossed that the "email" option must be there, how it is said in the documentation:

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/monitors/#email-as-a-destination

I'm using 7.8.0 and running from tarball.

In the Opendistro forum I found this topic, but I cannot understand how to solve it.
https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/e-mail-option-in-dropdown-missing/3909

Thanks for you attention

Answer (score 1):

Definitively version 7.8.0 doesn't have email alerting implementation...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if both opendistroforelasticsearch and opendistroforelasticsearch-kibana are upgraded?